# Jersey 2 AnnotatedClassVisitor has interface jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor as super class

Tags: java, jersey-2.0

I keep getting this error when migrating to Jersey 2.
At fist I though it is some Maven issue but it does not looks like that.
I keep getting:
AnnotatedClassVisitor has interface jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor as super class

my Maven look like that:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.15</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
        <version>2.15</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>2.15</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-jdk-http</artifactId>
        <version>2.15</version>
    </dependency>
```

Any idea will be helpfull

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably have Jersey 1.x Server module on your class-path. This module (before version 1.19) contains repackaged ASM 3 where `ClassVisitor` is still an interface. Remove the 1.x dependencies from your code and should be fine.

Note: Jersey 2.x Server module also contains repackaged ASM. But the repackaged ASM is newer, version 5, and `ClassVisitor` there is already an abstract class.

Comment: Yep you are right running 'mvn dependency:tree' reviled that Atmosphere framework adds Jersey 1.18.1 jars.